# Proof by induction that $n^2 - 1$ is divisible by 8 with $n \in \mathbb {2N+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, divisibility, proof-explanation

Here is the proof for the statement above:

$\underline{n=1:} \qquad$  $ 8 \mid 0$

$\underline{n=2k +1:}\qquad$ $8 \mid (2k+1)^2 -1 \qquad \forall k \in \mathbb N$

$\underline{n=2k+3:}$

$\begin{align}(2k+3)^2 -1& = 4k^2 + 12k + 9 - 1\\
& = 4(k^2 + 3k +2)\\
& = 4\cdot(k+1)\cdot(k+2)
\end{align}$

From here on I want to separate this into two cases $k\in \mathbb {2N}$ and $k\in \mathbb {2N+1}$. Because if $k$ is even than $4k$ is just a multiple of $8$ and if $k$ is uneven 4k isn't a multiple of 8 but $(k+1)$ will become even which makes the product then a multiple of 8.

> Is the above proof correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: your answer to your question is fine!

Comment: @Mr.Chip Is it correct?

Comment: @Math-fun Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @Anonymous I Usually, up votes are for questions that are well constructed and reflect thorough research. I suspect that your request may have had the opposite effect.

Comment: @AnonymousI I think my confirmation was a bit careless, sorry for that!

Comment: $$(2k + 1)^2 - 1 = (2k + 1 + 1)(2k + 1 - 1) = (2k + 2)(2k) = 2(k+1)(2k)=4k(k+1)$$ Although this is not proof by induction; just a comment.

Comment: @user477343 So what I've done is ok? Thx for the comment. PS: I still need some practice in algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @AnonymousI yes you did ok, but I commented in that respect because the proof is not fully inductive. You had your base case, but the inductive hypothesis and inductive step were a bit disorganised, however you managed to build a fine proof. I only commented what I did to serve as a bit of a hint, but I guess it served little because you say you need more practice. To explain in that regard, if there are two values $a$ and $b$, one has, $$a^2-b^2 = a^2-ab+ab-b^2 = a(a-b) + b(a-b) = (a+b)(a-b).$$ You could also find the value of $c$ in the equation, $$a^2-b^2 = (a-b)^2 + c,$$ if you prefer.

Comment: I understand what you have written but  I need more practice in algebraic manipulation in general. Because sometimes in inductive proofs I don't know how to use it in the n +1 case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $k+1$ step involves $2k + 1$. Instead it should involve $2(k+1) + 1 = 2k + 3$:

$$(2k+3)^2 - 1 = 4k^2 + 12k + 8 = 4k^2 + 4k + 8k + 8 = ((2k+1)^2 - 1) + 8(k+1),$$
and both terms on the RHS are divisble by 8 by the inductive hypothesis.

Do note also that your proof is not actually inductive – while it's a perfectly fine proof of the statement in question, you're not using mathematical induction.

Comment: I actually meant that becuase I always right n= k or n= k+1 as just a convention. I just implemented directly the uneven numbers to it.

Comment: I'll edit it the question.

Answer (score 1):

A proof by induction means that you do two things:

- You prove it is true for the $n=1$
- You prove it is true for $n+1$ taking as hypothesis it is true for $n$.

Here we should be careful because $n \in 2\mathbb N+1$, for instance $n=2k+1$, with $k \in \mathbb N$. Then the next term is $2k+3$.

Let's assume we have $8|(2k+1)^2-1$

Let's take the next element $(2k+3)^2-1=4k^2+12k+8=(4k^2+4k)+(8k+8)=((2k+1)^2-1)+8(k+1)$

We have obviously $8|8(k+1)$ and the we have also $8|(4k^2+4k)$ due to the hypothesis.

Comment: But then in the I.H. you'll get $4k(k+1)$ for each $k \in N$ which isn't true for the uneven numbers. Then do you need to clarify that too in that case?

Comment: $4k(k+1)$ is always divisible by $8$, since $k(k+1)$ is always divisible by $2$...